# Programmatically get OSX Fusion Drive information

Tags: macos, mount, iostat, diskarbitration

I'm working on a project that links drives (and their associated stats, such as those displayed by `iostat`) and partitions to mount points, but running into issues with the way OS X does the [Fusion Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive).

I have been able to gather information on drives and partitions from the [IO Registry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/TheRegistry/TheRegistry.html) and [Disk Arbitration Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Conceptual/DiskArbitrationProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Similarly, I have been able to correlate drives and mount points using [statfs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/statfs.2.html) (or the `mount` or `df` commands).  However, there is a missing link where the Fusion Drive enters the picture.  Here's a sample output of `diskutil list`:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            999.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +999.3 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 FA33A826-C98E-425A-BCF1-9A68A926D36E
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

The IORegistry statistics from `iostat` (reads/writes/bytes read/bytes written,time spent transferring, etc.) are associated with `disk0` in the above output.   However, `df` (or equivalent programmatic statfs functions) associates the `/` mount point with `/dev/disk1`:

```
$ df
Filesystem                        512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                        1951825920  575057552 1376256368    30% 71946192 172032046   29%   /
```

I want to be able to correlate reads/writes on the filesystem at `/` with the physical drive `disk0`.  I've spent several hours searching here and elsewhere for any way to associate `disk1` with `disk0s2`.  The source code for `diskutil` is apparently in the `DiskManagement` Framework, which is not public.

Is there any way, other than textually parsing the output of the above `diskutil list` command, to associate a mounted (virtual) fusion drive with its underlying (physical) partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more hours of digging, I uncovered the key fact that Fusion Drives (as well as the full-disk FileVault encryption introduced in Lion) utilize a feature called "Core Storage" (or CoreStorage) where one or more physical disks/partitions is linked to a virtual disk.

There does not seem to be any publicly available API to obtain CoreStorage information programmatically, and what commands there are are sparsely documented.

While still a command line, `diskutil cs list` provides sufficient parseable information to make the connections I need.

A P[DF with examples and a lot more information can be found here](http://public.z-effects.com/CoreStorageTraining.pdf).